# Oracle to SQL Server query migration results into: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, t-sql

The following Oracle query needs to be migrated to T-SQL but the following error appears:

> The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived
>   tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET
>   or FOR XML is also specified.

Oracle can handle the code below without errors.

Removing the ORDER BY does not help at all.

```
SELECT CREATIONDATE, TITLE, SUM(myindex) over (ORDER BY CREATIONDATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cumula
FROM (
SELECT CREATIONDATE, TITLE, 1 as myindex
FROM CONTENT
WHERE CONTENTID in (
        SELECT CONTENTID 
        FROM CONTENT_LABEL
        WHERE LABELID in (SELECT LABELID FROM LABEL WHERE name = 'retrospective')
)
AND CONTENTTYPE = 'PAGE'
AND CONTENT_STATUS = 'current'
ORDER BY CREATIONDATE)
```

The exact error is: The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.

Can you please help me out migrating the query to SQL?
Thanks

Comment: Don't use a subquery.  It isn't necessary.  Or remove the `ORDER BY`.  It is useless in subqueries under most circumstances.

Comment: the order by should be outside the subquery select as the error said

Comment: Where's you `GROUP BY`?

Comment: removing the ORDER BY


results into: Incorrect syntax near ')'.
any ideas?

Comment: @Larnu, that's a windowing `SUM` to create a running total. He doesn't need a `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're facing two issues here.

1) As noted by a few others, the `ORDER BY CREATIONDATE` in the sub-query has to go.

2) SQL Server (along with Postgres and probably others) has a requirement that you alias a sub-query when it's in the `FROM` clause. This is the syntax error it's throwing after you take out that `ORDER BY`. You can call it anything. When I don't care, my default is `'s'`, for "sub-query".

```
SELECT CREATIONDATE, TITLE, SUM(myindex) over (ORDER BY CREATIONDATE ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS cumula
FROM 
(
SELECT CREATIONDATE, TITLE, 1 as myindex
FROM CONTENT
WHERE CONTENTID in 
        (
        SELECT CONTENTID 
        FROM CONTENT_LABEL
        WHERE LABELID in (SELECT LABELID FROM LABEL WHERE name = 'retrospective')
        )
AND CONTENTTYPE = 'PAGE'
AND CONTENT_STATUS = 'current'
/*ORDER BY CREATIONDATE*/
) AS s; --<--- Five extra characters, and you should be good to go.
```

Comment: Thanks Eric. Your comment about aliasing the sub queries was a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the error message, you can't use `ORDER BY` to sort rows in the derived table.

The order of rows in the result set is  controlled by an `ORDER BY` clause in the outer `SELECT`, not by the `OVER` clause.

The `OVER` clause "specifies the logical order in which the window function calculation is performed". It doesn't sort the result set either.